# Migrating breaking change using angular ng-update schematic

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, angular-library, typescript-compiler-api, angular-schematics

Unable to run custom ng update schematic. The goal is to traverse html files and search for certain dom attributes, however I am unsure how to properly traverse the Tree structure in an angular application. I have not found a great deal online regarding this and am hoping for some results here. Below is my Rule factory for how I am currently trying to access the file system.

```
export default function MigrationUpdate(_options: any): Rule {
  return (host: Tree, _context: SchematicContext) => {
    
    //Traverse file system in angular application
    //Searching for html files 
    host.getDir('/files').visit(filePath => {
      if (!filePath.endsWith('.html')) {
        return;
      }
      const text = host.read(filePath);
      if (text === null) {
        throw new SchematicsException('Unable to read file path.');
      }
    });

    return host;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this here as I have seen other developers come across this issue. To properly access a projects file structure, getDir() takes a string argument which represents the file path for that project. First retrieve the appropriate project using getWorkSpace(), found from [here](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/13/angular-schematics). Set the options.path that will be passed into getDir() as the src directory file.

```
export default function (options: any): Rule {
  return (host: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
    
    const workspace = getWorkspace(host);
    if(!options.project){
      options.project = Object.keys(workspace.projects)[0];
    }
    const project = workspace.projects[options.project];
    options.path = join(normalize(project.root), 'src');

    host.getDir(options.path).visit(file => {
      if (file.endsWith('component.html')) {
        context.logger.log('info','Successfully found HTML files'); 
      }
    });

    return host;
  };
}
```